# How can I make the spear collide with any *single* frog object that is part of an ArrayList, and have only that speared frog be affected?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, collision

The user is controlling a spear to spear frogs on the screen. The spear and frog objects have corresponding rects, and so do the frogs. I am having difficulty making it so that if the spear interacts with one of the frogs, only that frog is affected. For the sake of this questions, let's pretend there are three frogs on the screen and that the spear is the the first one in the ArrayList of spears.

```
for (int i = 0; i < frogs.size(); i++) {
    if(Rect.intersects(frogs.get(i).getRect(), spears.get(i).getHandleRect())
       && !frogs.get(i).isTapped) {
           frog.get(i).speared = true;
    }
}
```

If I do it this way, then the spear can only spear the frog that is also the first element of the frogs ArrayList. If I use a for each loop (Frog frog : frogs), spearing one frog makes all of them "speared". Perhaps there is a simple command I'm unfamiliar with?

If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask.

Edit:

```
for(int i = 0; i < frogNumber;i++) {
  Frog b = new Frog(randX, i * 2 + 800, FROG_WIDTH, FROG_HEIGHT);
  frogs.add(b);
} //frog initialization
```

Comment: does your if statement return? Nothing relevant in remove //code?

Comment: what's wrong with your solution?

Comment: Each frog has a corresponding spear... If one is tapped, only that one is slashed, and the others are fine, right? frogs.get(i).kill() should work for the one, right? From what I see and read, it seems fine... But should have also been fine for the foreach situation

Comment: mh you said the spear is the first one in the ArrayList of Spears, yet you wrote `spears.get(i).getHandleRect()`, shouldn't it be `spears.get(0).getHandleRect()`?

Comment: So let's say it is the 0th iteration and you are using the first spear. The 0th spear can only interact with the 0th frog, you know what I am saying? So If the user moves the spear and slashes the 2nd frog object in the arraylist, so to speak, nothing happens.

Comment: @Onheiron the if statement returns true if the 0th spear contacts the 0th spear. if the 0th spear contacts the "2nd" frog, nothing happens which is the problem.

Comment: @Danielson The for each situtation doesn't work because it checks if the spear contacted any of the frogs, so if one is contacted, then they all die.

Comment: @mckamike can you post the Frog initialization, and the line where you kill the Frog? perhaps the Frogs share the object for being alive and dead

Comment: @Danielson Yes, I will add it by editing my OP

Comment: @Danielson@Danielson The frog is killed in the Frog class, in which all I say is if speared is true, then give it 0 velocity and draw an image of a dead frog. If I am not mistaken, isn't an ArrayList a list of objects, so each frog my be an object of the same Frog class, but are independent objects themselves? If I didn't answer your question adequately let me know.

Comment: @mckamike I was trying to reproduce your code, when I saw `new Frog(randX, i * 2 + 800, FROG_WIDTH, FROG_HEIGHT);` would  it help if you do `new Frog(randX, i * (2 + 800), FROG_WIDTH, FROG_HEIGHT);` because the `y` coordinate are `0, 802, 804, 806`, and x is constant. whereas as I propose it will be: 0, 802, 1604, 2406 (because the `*` operator takes precedence over `+`)... Which is dependent on the widths and heights of the Frogs... If not, can you post a mockup so that I can compile? So Frog class, Rect class and Spear class?

Comment: @Danielson Danielson, thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Would you rather have me zip the actually contents of it to you so that you can open it in Android Studio?

Comment: Sounds good, you can send to daniel{dot}hohle{at}gmail{dot}com (I'll delete this post afterwards)

Comment: @Danielson I actually found a fix today. I'll post the answer tomorrow. Thanks again for your generosity

Comment: That is good to hear! And your welcome